# R strptime to 00h00 Format

Tags: r, strptime

How can I strptime a character like "15/09/2016 20h26"?

I searched this on the strptime official manual and arround the Stack overflow, but I didn't find anything that could help me.

I tried this code:

```
u <- ("15/09/2016 20h26")
strptime(u, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

and

```
strptime(u, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H'h'%M")
```

Anyone has any idea of what I need to do?

Edit:

Firstly, sorry for the clearness of the question.

I tried to use a sample to describe my problem, but it seems like a typo.

I have a txt file with 400 observations of time in the format "20/01/2016 14h00". I'm trying to convert this to date with strptime:

here is my code:

```
y <- read.table('materias_data.txt', sep = ";")
l <- strptime(y, format = "%d/%m/%Y %Hh%M")
```

I got this error when I run the code:

> Error in strptime(y, format = "%d/%m/%Y %Hh%M") :     input string is
>   too long

What can I do to convert correctly the data.frame?

Edit 2: Solution

Reading the comments I realized what the problem is:

strptime doesn't work to data.frame but it works on characters.

The step to solve this is

```
y <- read.table('materias_data.txt', sep = ";")
l <- strptime(y[,1], format = "%d/%m/%Y %Hh%M")
df <- data.frame(l)
```

Thank You

Comment: @ZheyuanLI I'm afraid that this question isn't a typo. When I use the "%d/%m/%Y %Hh%M", an NA is returned.  Maybe my question wasn't clear, so I wiil edit to be more specific.

Comment: What? `strptime("15/09/2016 20h26", format = '%d/%m/%Y %Hh%M')` works.

Comment: @alistaire It works to only one sample, I believe my question wasn't clear, now I edited. Sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: Try using the vector from the data.frame?

Comment: Why do you think `strptime` would work on a data frame when the help file says it should be a character vector?

Comment: if it's a single-column data frame you would want `l[[1]] <- strptime(l[[1]],...)`. More generally I guess `l[] <- lapply(l,strptime,format=...)` ...

Comment: @RIchScriven You're right, after I convert the data.frame to character worked. Thank You. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relatively new [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) package I added to [CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/index.html) parses this automatically without extra help:

```
R> anytime("15/09/2016 20h26")
[1] "2016-09-15 20:26:00 CDT"
R>
```

Another nice feature is that it also automatically converts from `factor` (or `ordered`) to `character`.

So if you have a data.frame `df` with a column of values like this in, say, a column called `datestr` then just pass the column:

```
R> anytime( df[, "datestr"] )
```

which you can assign to a new column in the data.frame as well:

```
R> df[, "parsedtime"] <- anytime( df[, "datestr"] )
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank's for your help.

Comment: Had an opportunity to use `anytime` for a work project this week. ++gd pkg, Dirk.

Comment: There is [one weird open bug report](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/issues/5) I cannot replicate or explain, but otherwise it is indeed quite useful.  Also noticed that it fails on (bad) single digit m/d/Y like 9/9/2016 -- only 09/09/2016 will fly.  Oh well.  I mostly just got tired of a bunch of stoooopid repeat conversion from yyyymmdd as int, or char, or ... and wanted nice hammer for that nail....

Comment: The `anytime` package saved me 30 minutes of processing time on a year's worth of honeypot timestamp data today, @DirkEddelbuettel. It's a keeper, especially `anydate`. Sooooooo much faster than `as.Date()`.

Comment: I think there are possible speedups we could make. It's goal wasn't even to be fast -- Simon's [fasttime](https://twitter.com/revodavid/status/783072836449468416) cannot be beat, though it does of course only support _one_ format -- but to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr`'s `mutate` to apply the transformation data.frame-wise, or use one of the apply functions:

```
y <- y %>% mutate(col_name = as.POSIXct(col_name, format = "%d/%m/%Y %Hh%M"))
# or
parsed <- sapply(y$col_name, strptime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %Hh%M")
```

Comment: `mutate` is for a single column.  I think you meant `mutate_each`