# R strptime function with a specified format argument reverts back to default

Tags: r, strptime

I simply want to convert dates with a single-digit month to month-day-year format with dashes. E.g. "07-15-2007". I have a char variable called "DATEDX_ROUGH" that looks like "7/15/2007", and I have tried the functions strptime() and anytime(), as recommended in this thread: [R strptime to 00h00 Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812348/r-strptime-to-00h00-format)

My one-liner:

```
df$DATEDX <- strptime(df$DATEDX_ROUGH, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```

However, (using strptime) when I specify format = "%m-%d-%Y", the new variable returns all NA's. So I tried using slashes instead of dashes. New one-liner:

```
df$DATEDX <- strptime(df$DATEDX_ROUGH, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

When I specify format = "%m/%d/%Y", the new variable returns the default formatting "2007-07-15 EDT."

Does anyone have any idea why this is? Am I missing something in the format argument?

Comment: `strptime` parses a string into a date value in R. Date values in R are always printed the same way by default to the console. The format you pass to the parser is not retained with the date values themselves. If you want to change how date values are printed, then you need to format them yourself back into a string. You can use the `strftime` function for that.

Comment: (Of course, converting to a string in the `%m-%d-%Y` format you wants disables any arithmetic operations and sorting, both feasible when the data is retained in the `Date`-class format of `%Y-%m-%d`. I'm not saying that that format is the best in the world (though I do prefer it personally), but consider the key distinction between how data is *stored* (including how it can be manipulated and sorted) and how it is *presented* in reports, tables, etc. I tend to suggest worrying about the format only for reports, not on the console itself.